# How to submit page in a new frame by clicking on another frame

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two frames on my web page as below
+--------+-----------------+
|------- |---------------- |
|------- |---------------- |
|------- |---------------- |
|-frame1 |-----frame2----- |
|------- |---------------- |
|------- |---------------- |
|------- |---------------- |
|------- |---------------- |
+--------+-----------------+

When i click on frame1 (navigation menu frame) it should display the contents on frame2 (content frame). But right now when i click on frame1, content frame is displayed on frame1 itself (overriding navigation menu frame).

I cannot use "target" option as the link for the page to display in frame2 is present in  instead of , I think i have to set the source from frame1 in onClick function as below

onClick = "document.getElementId ('frame1Id').src='frame2';

But this is not working as i'm seeing javascript error in firefox:
document.getElementById("frameId") is null

Can any one help me out in resolving this.

Comment: Complete your sentence: "I cannot use "target" option as the link for the page to display in frame2 is present in ??? instead of ???"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like:

```
onclick="window.top.frames['frame2'].src = 'newpage'"
```

if that doesn't work, try defining a function in the page that contains both frames

```
function setFrame2(src) {
    document.getElementById('frame2').src = src;
}
```

and in frame1

```
onclick="window.top.setFrame2('newpage');"
```

Comment: When i click on the link in frame1, I'm getting javascript error: window.top.setFrame2 is not a function. I'm just suspecting whether the id of frame can be accessed using document object?  I have got document.action available for the webpage to be displayed in frame2. I want to use this document.action somehow to display it in frame2?. Let me know if i'm not clear.